# How to correctly pass a SQL query as parameter in Jasper Reports?

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports

I've looked into all other questions regarding this topic and I followed all steps mentioned there, however I'm still getting an error when trying to pass an entire SQL statement as Parameter.

This is my SQLQuery Parameter:

```
<parameter name="SQLTag" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["SELECT * FROM REPORT_VER WHERE TAG BETWEEN  $P{Von}  AND $P{Bis}"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

I've checked it and the SQL works perfectly fine when passed directly into the Report SQL field. 
However because I want to have conditional SQL queries I need them passed through a parameter. Anyone knows what I'm missing?

I tried to use `$P{SQLTag}` and `$P!{SQLTag}` expressions at *queryString*/

Stack trace:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: Abnahme.
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:548)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$20(ReportControler.java:523)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: Abnahme.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:344)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1245)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:723)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:438)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:550)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:123)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case using parameters at *defaultValueExpression* you should operate with them as a common *Java* variable.

For example:

```
<parameter name="fieldFilter" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["someValue"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="query" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field = '" + $P{fieldFilter} + "'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[$P!{query}]]>
</queryString>
```

or like this:

```
<parameter name="intFieldFilter" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[2017]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="strFieldFilter" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["someValue"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="query" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[String.format("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field = '%1$s' AND trunc(date_field, 'yyyy') = trunc(to_date(%2$d, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy')", $P{strFieldFilter}, $P{intFieldFilter})]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[$P!{query}]]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've changed my parameter to `<parameter name="SQLTag" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
   <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["SELECT * FROM REPORT_VER WHERE TAG BETWEEN '" + $P{Von} + "' AND '" + $P{Bis} + "'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
  </parameter>` still getting same results...

Comment: `$P{Von}` and `$P{Bis}` are both `java.util.Date` and yes it worked perfectly fine passed directly into the *queryString* without parameters

Comment: What is a valid sql query with constants (without parameters)? Post the sample, please

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM REPORT_VER WHERE TAG BETWEEN '10.05.2015' AND '20.05.2015'"`

Comment: It means that you need format dates (Date) as String (with help of *SimpleDateFormat*, for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works now! Shame on me I didn't consider that yet